# on multiplying weight into price i'm getting the total price as a multiplication of string but I want integer as total price

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, django-views

veiws.py:

```
def sell(request):
    global Price
    Metal = "Metal"
    Steel = "Steel"
    copper = "copper"
    plastic = "plastic"
    Aluminium = "Aluminium"

    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.user
        Scrap = request.POST.get('Scrap', '')
        Weight = request.POST.get('Weight', '')
        Address1 = request.POST.get('Address1', '')
        Address2 = request.POST.get('Address2', '')
        locality = request.POST.get('locality', '')

        if Scrap.__eq__(Metal):
            Price = 12
        elif Scrap.__eq__(Steel):
            Price = 10
        elif Scrap.__eq__(copper):
            Price = 6
        elif Scrap.__eq__(plastic):
            Price = 2
        elif Scrap.__eq__(Aluminium):
            Price = 30
        x = Price
        price = float(x)

        Total_price = price * Weight

        order = Orders(Scrap=Scrap, Total_Price=Total_price, Weight=Weight, Address1=Address1, Address2=Address2,
                       locality=locality, user=user)
        order.save()

        thank = True
        id = order.order_id
        return render(request, 'Main/sell.html', {'thank': thank, 'id': id})
    return render(request, 'Main/sell.html',)
```

models.py

[image]

**selling form**

I chose metal whose price is 12 and weight I have taken 12 kg so as the total price I should get 144
[image]

But i am getting this
[image]

Comment: So, cast it to integer ??

Answer (score 0):

I thin client sends the `weight` as string. You can convert it to number.

`Total_price = price * iny(Weight)`